# require statement not working properly with Titanium SDK 8.0.0.GA

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I have a classic titanium app, for some reason the require statement is not working properly

For example:

```
require("views/Player");
```

The required file is supposed to modify a global variable, but after requiring it the global variable is not modified.

**The weirdest thing that it works fine when compiling against Ti SDK 7.4.2.GA and doesn't work when compiling against any newer version.**

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it turned out that prior to SDK 7.5.0, the app.js would assign any top-level variables to the global object. But not after that.

To fix it, you should declare global variables like this

```
global.labelText = 'Titanium Doesn't Rock!';
```

instead of this

```
var labelText = 'Titanium Doesn't Rock!';
```

More info here: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_SDK_7.5.0_Functionality_Update

Comment: Global variables should be avoided whenever you can. Instead of doing a require to modify, why not use the require to just provide you with the variable instead?

Comment: Hello Rene!
Actually, this is a legacy project I was trying to debug for a quick fix.
Unfortunately, this pattern is used throughout the app  I had to deal with it.